# How to omit Cucumber JS scenarios based on tags in Cypress tests?

Tags: cucumber, cypress, cucumberjs

In my Cypress / Cucumber JS framework, I have several scenarios that have different tags (`@Regression`, `@Login`, & `@Smoke`, etc.).

I am trying to run all scenarios except those with the `@Login` tag.

I am able to run ***only*** the `@Login` tests with the below command:

`npx cypress open --config specPattern=cypress/tests/e2e/*.feature --env tags=@Login`

I tried the below 2 commands that I found online, but I'm running into issues with those:

1. `npx cypress open --config specPattern=cypress/tests/e2e/*.feature --env tags=not @Login`

> Error: Your configFile threw an error from cypress.config.js
> The error was thrown while executing your e2e.setupNodeEvents() function:
> Error: empty stack
> at pop (C:...\node_modules@cucumber\tag-expressions\dist\src\index.js:139:15)

2. `npx cypress open --config specPattern=cypress/tests/e2e/*.feature --env tags=~@Login`

This second attempt does open the Cypress Explorer, but it says that no specs were found. Even though I do have tests with tags other than `@Login`.

I know I could specify all the other tags, & run it that way, but I instead want to just exclude `@Login` tests.

Can someone please point out what I am doing incorrectly?

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried putting some quotes around the parameter?

```js
npx cypress open --env tags="not @Login"
```

Comment: I tried your answer, but I was still getting the 'No specs were found' message.
I instead used this script in package.json - `"open": "cypress open --env tags=\"not @Login\""`. This does work. I think the issue trying to use yours is the single vs double quotes

Comment: Of course quote marks, Thank-you. Too obvious!